# How to get a list/array from a view back to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, list, view, controller

My ViewResult Controller:

```
    public ViewResult Controller(int id)
    {
        List<Data> dataList = dataAccess.getDataById(id);
        Results[] resultArray = new Results[dataList.Count];
        ViewBag.results= resultArray;
        return View(dataList);
    }
```

My View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Solution.Models.Data>

@{
    Solution.Models.Results[] res= ViewBag.results;
}


@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
<table>
@{

    int i = 0;
    foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            Snippet: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.text)
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Translation: @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => res[i].text)
        </td>
    </tr>
    i++;
    }
}
</table>
<p>
    <input class="CRUD-buttons" type="submit" value="Send" />
</p>
}
```

My Controller ActionResult:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Controller(/*List<Data> dataList, */Results[] results)
    {
        ResultText = results[0].text; //NullReferenceException
    }
```

dataList and results are empty. I read a couple of posts on stackoverflow, but could not find a solution.

I took already a look on the following blog ([link](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/)) but its MVC 2 code. :(

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# MVC 3: ". That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do this. What gets you here is that in order for you to receive the `results` parameter, the `name` for the generated edit controls should be `results[0]` for the first, `results[1]` for the second, etc with no gaps in the indexes (this is because of [how `DefaultModelBinder` expects to find the fields named](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) when the form is posted).

So one immediate (although not very good) solution would be to specify the name correctly:

```
@Html.TextBox(string.Format("results[{0}]", i), res[i].text)
```

**A much better solution** would be to put the `results` into your model (better yet, in a ViewModel created specifically for this view). For example, first of all you create a class that encapsulates one piece of data and the corresponding result:

```
class ItemViewModel
{
    Solution.Models.Data TheData { get; set; }
    Solution.Models.Results TheResults { get; set; }
}
```

You then make your view have a collection of these items as its model:

```
@model IEnumerable<ItemViewModel>
```

and then output the edit control with

```
Translation: @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.TheResults)
```

Finally, you modify the postback action to accept an array of `ItemViewModel`:

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Controller(ItemViewModel[] results)
```

**General piece of advice:** Try to avoid using `EditorFor` with objects that are not part of your view's model (for example, things you have passed through `ViewBag` or `ViewData`). If you do this, MVC will punish you.